# can i log stuff from within a drools file?

Tags: logging, drools

I have a drools file.

I would like to print to the std:out when some logic fails. Like, the same place that my System.out.println() would print to.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java code on the RHS(when) side of your rules. So, simply calling `System.out.println()` should work.

Also you can pass in a logger, but I think you'll have to use a Drools global variable for this.